# How to put Sub query result of two columns into two alias for MySQL Views

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I am trying to create MySQL view with sub queries and Sub queries has multiple columns and I want to put result of these two columns into two alias as per below.
Please help to check if it is possible.
Org_Code and count(Transaction_ID) result I am trying to assign to alias Code and Count.

**- View is not working for two column**-
create view Test1 as
select
(select Org_CODE, count(Transaction_ID) from ekyc_table where Transaction_DATE between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE() group by Org_CODE) as Code, Count,
(select Org_CODE, count(Transaction_ID) from ekyc_table where Transaction_ID='Y' AND Transaction_DATE between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE() group by Org_CODE) as Code, Count
from dual;

**- This View is working for One column.**
create view Test2 as
select
(select count(Transaction_ID) from ekyc_table where Transaction_DATE between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()) as Total_Count,
(select count(Transaction_ID) from ekyc_table where Transaction_ID='Y' AND Transaction_DATE between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()) as Total_Success_Count
from dual;

Comment: Hi Ketan, Can you share two-two rows of each, I'll create a query for you then.

Comment: Not Working Two column view   I am not sure how will it look, two column result.
Code Count Code1 Count1
InfoTech 300         InfoTech 200
AiroCel 400        AiroCel 300
ITC        537           ITC       447                                                                                                              --> Working One column view (This one is working and looks like this simple) 
Total_Count Total_Success_Count
500             300